# The mocking of observable contains the missing values

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to mock the return type of observable. As you can see below the statement in the configureTestSuite  new Observable

```
export class AgreementsModel {
    userAgreementId: number;
    agreementId: number;
    code: string;
    userAgreementStateId: number;
    userAgreementStateName: string;
    acceptanceWindowExpiry: Date;
    version: string;
    data: string;
    authoredById: number;
    authoredByName: string;
    authored: Date;
    issuedById: number;
    issuedByName: string;
    issued: Date;
  }




import { AgreementsModel } from '../../agreements/models/agreements.model';



export const AgreementModelMock: AgreementsModel = <AgreementsModel>{
agreementId: 1,
data: '<html> </html>'
};



  configureTestSuite(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SharedModule, FontAwesomeModule],
      declarations: [AgreementComponent, CustomScrollDirective],
      providers: [{ provide: UserService, useValue: mockUserService },
      { provide: AgreementsService, useValue:  new Mock<AgreementsService>({
           getOutstandingAgreements: () => new Observable<AgreementsModel[]>(),
           updateAgreement: () => Promise.resolve([])
         }).Object }]
    });
  });
```

Comment: If i do it like this   getOutstandingAgreements: () => new Observable<AgreementModelMock[]>(), . I get a message that it refers to a value but is being used as type here

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're using it as a type in that instance. To mock the observable, use `of`;

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
getOutstandingAgreements: () => of(/*whatever value you want here for the mock*/);
// if you want to be able to change the value of this observable, 
you have to assign it to a behaviorSubject that will be a variable and  you can next on it
```